# MATLAB IDE: F1-key and doc function displays help for the wrong function

Tags: matlab, ide, documentation, shortcut

I've been working for some time on a MATLAB function to retrieve file names. The function is called `getFileName`. My problem is that when I try to display help for this function by pressing the `F1` key *while cursor is on the function name*, I instead, get the help for the built in function `matlab.io.hdf4.sd.getFilename`. I get the same if I write `doc getFileName` in my command window. Only if I type `helpwin getFileName` do I get the correct documentation displayed!

This doesn't make sense to me since MATLAB is case sensitive and thereby `getFileName` is different from `getFilename`. Furthermore, when I type `which getFileName` (or for some strange reason, if I type `which getFilename`), I get the path to my function and not to the built-in function `matlab.io.hdf4.sd.getFilename`.

So my question is: is it possible to make sure that the function you get documentation for (by pressing the `F1` key) is the same function that you run if you type the name of that function?

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using, and which OS?

Comment: I'm using MATLAB R2014a on a pc with Windows 7 Enterprise (64 bit) Service Pack 1

Answer (score 0):

Matlab isn't actually case sensitive for the help files.  In the terminal you can type

```
doc PLOT
```

and it will still pop up the documentation for the proper plot function.

I don't know where these files are stored on PC, as I use a Mac, but in the Matlab directory if you search for an uncommon file name (like plotyy) you will see the source file, but you'll also find an html file that doc uses.  If you write an html file for the new file it should bring up the right info for the documentation center.

Matlab used to just copy the commented text at the beginning of the file into the documentation center in older versions of matlab, but now it uses html files stored on your drive.  I don't know if this will definitely fix your problem as I haven't written an html file for an "almost overloaded" function.

Also, about the weird 'which' thing, I'm pretty sure Matlab first searches the first entry on your path list for a close match, and the current directory is on the top of the list.  If you type 'path' into the console it will output all the search paths, and the top ones are searched first.

I apologize for masquerading as if this is an 'Answer' but I don't have enough reputation points to add this as a comment.